# Maximum principle, quantitative version

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle, laplacian

Is it true that

$$
\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq C\|\Delta f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}+C\|f\|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)}
$$
for all $f\in C^2(\Omega)$ and smooth $\Omega$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M=\|\Delta f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$. Consider $f^{\pm}(x):=f\pm \frac{M}{2}|x-x_0|^2$ for some $x_0\in \Omega$. Then $f^{\pm}$ is sub/super harmonic, and by the maximum principle

$$
\sup_{x\in\Omega} f\leq \sup_{x\in\Omega} f^{+}\leq \sup_{x\in\partial\Omega} f^+\leq \|f\|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)}+\frac{M}{2}\text{diam}(\Omega)^2
$$

and

$$
\inf_{x\in\Omega}f\geq\inf_{x\in\Omega} f^{-}\geq \inf_{x\in\partial\Omega} f^-\geq -\|f\|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)}-\frac{M}{2}\text{diam}(\Omega)^2
$$

thus

$$
\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq \|f\|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)}+C\|\Delta f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}.
$$